# Vue.js cannot access to nested properties of data object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-component

In Vue.js I fetch some data of a json-file like this:

```
export default {
    data () {
       return {
           data: []
       }   
    },
    created () {
        this.fetchData();    
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData () {
            $.getJSON('data/api.json', function(el) {
                this.data = el;
            }.bind(this)),
        }
    }
}
```

The fetched data has the following structure:

```
{
    time: '17:00',
    pick: {
        box: {
            single: 1,
            multi: 2
        }    
    }
}
```

When I try to access to `{{ data.pick.box }} or {{ data.pick.box.single }}` in my component, I always get this error message:

```
vue.js?3de6:2963 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'box' of undefined
at Proxy.render (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:126), <anonymous>:4:46)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:2954:22)
at VueComponent.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:2191:21)
at Watcher.get (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:1656:27)
at new Watcher (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:1648:12)
at VueComponent.Vue._mount (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:2190:19)
at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:5978:15)
at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:8305:16)
at init (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:2502:11)
at createComponent (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:139), <anonymous>:4052:9)
```

Is there any restriction for accessing deep nested objects? When I call `{{ data }}`, for example, I get the whole data structure displayed as a string correctly.

As mentioned by Nora, here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rs23vf3/)

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: When rendering for the first time `data` is `[]`, and does not have any `.pick.box` property.

Comment: You can use [v-if](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) as I have mentioned in my answer, if you dont want to use one extra variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try waiting for data to finish loading to display it in your template:

```
export default {
    data () {
       return {
           loading: false,
           data: []
       }   
    },
    created () {
        this.fetchData();    
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData () {
            this.loading = true;
            $.getJSON('data/api.json', function(el) {
                this.data = el;
                this.loading = false;
            }.bind(this)),
        }
    }
}
```

In template:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!loading">
    {{ data.pick.box }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I had the same problem but this solution didn't work for me. I just changed lifecycle hook from mounted() to create() and it worked. Anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You are getting this error, as the `data` is not populated while it is being loaded, and you get error in that while. You can use [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) in your template till the data is populated in the view. So the element will not be rendered till the data is loading and once the data is loaded it will show the data.

It can be like following:

```
<div v-if="data.pick">
  {{data.pick.box}}
</div>
```

Comment: love easy solutions

Comment: this is not working if u have multiple calls for this nested object

Comment: saved me from a whole lot of trouble

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create an empty object with empty properties.

```
 data () {
       return {
           loading: false,
           data: {pick:{},}
       }   
    },
```